# Needing help on this, adding another switch to existing switch for fan and light to turn on separate with a bit of a curveball!

Tags: electrical, switch, ceiling-fan

[image: Photo 2][image: Photo 1]Spent all day trying to figure this out without any luck! I am trying to add an additional switch to an existing one with the end goal of being able to turn on the fan from one switch and the light with the other.

**Existing wires and hardware:**
12-2 coming into the box from the panel. 14/3 from the switch box to the ceiling fan. Two single pole switches. 12-2 coming into the box that sends power to the bathroom on the other side of the bedroom wall (vanity light and bath fan on independent switches).

**How I wired it in the switch box:**
Attached to the 12-2 power wire that is connected to the panel, I have wire nut connecting the black hot to the black wire headed into the bathroom as well as two pigtails that provide power to each switch. The switch with the red switch leg is for the light and the other switch's switch leg is for the fan. All neutrals are wire nutted together (one neutral coming from the panel, one that goes into the bathroom, and one from the 14/3 wire going to the ceiling fan. All grounds are wired together with two additional pigtails, one for each switch.

**How I wired it inside the ceiling fan box**
All three grounds are wired together (one for the fan, one to the fan bracket, one from the 14/3 traveling from the switch box). Red wire from one of the switches is connected to the blue (light) wire on the ceiling fan. Black wire from the other switch is connected to the black wire on the ceiling fan. White neutrals are wired together (one from the fan and one from the 14/3 wire from the switch box.

**My problem**
Essentially I have wired it like the diagram in the attached photo the only difference is the addition of the 12/2 wire that heads into the bathroom. My issue here is the switch with the red switch leg (right hand one) doesn't do anything when flipped on. Furthermore this switch has to be flipped on for the other switch (left one) to turn on the light, which is the wrong one for the light control. Once the light is on by flipping on the right switch then the left switch, either switch can turn the light back off again? It seems like the power is jumping back and forth between the switches? I should note that the bathroom vanity light and fan work as they should regardless of what position the ceiling fan switches are in. I spent many hours looking for the answer but no such luck on the interweb and thought I give this group of smart people a try. Does anyone know what to do here?  [![Diagram I followed[[image: Switchboxswitchbox]

Comment: The diagram is correct. The only answer I see is that you didn't follow it correctly. Please add photographs of the wiring in the box. Turn off the power at the breaker, pull the switches out with wires connected and photograph them from all angles. You probably won't be able to add more than one or two photos but if you can put them up on a site like Imager and add the links here, someone will be able to add them all.

Comment: @DoxyLover Thank you for your reply, I have uploaded photos like you suggested. I Tried to do it in the original post but failed to realize the file size was too big. I hope this shows my error that I can't find. Thanks for your comment!!

Comment: The diagram looks correct. But there are bigger issues:  You mentioned the 12 ga going to the bathroom and tapping off that circuit using 14/3. Is this a new run to the ceiling fan/light? If so, several things wrong: 14/3 rated at 15 amps, the breaker for that would need to be downsized to 15amps. But you can't do that because current code require bathrooms to have a 20 amp circuit. Next, bathroom circuits for outlets are supposed to be DEDICATED circuits, you can't share that with other locations according to current code.

Comment: Sounds like you might not have correctly identified how power comes into this. The diagram would work if that was how it was actually wired. Your symptoms suggest that one switch is switching the power to the other switch. There's also the problem that others mentioned of commingling the (supposed to be) 20A dedicated bathroom circuit with non-bathroom uses on 14Ga wire (15A breaker maximum)

Comment: Was that 14-3 already in the wall, or was that a cable you ran?